# how to display php search engine execution time and number of results before the results

Tags: php, html, css, search-engine

ok so i built a php search engine and it was working beautifully, but some people said to me that it was slow.

maybe it may appear slow on their machines when the thing outputs the results table on html but i know it's running ludicrously fast.

so i decided to make a fancy feature like the one many search engines like google have saying that ''your search returned X results in Y time'' as a way of telling people that probably isn't my search engine fault that they're taking a long time to see the results for their query.

i've made the feature that pretty much confirms what i already know, that is that the search engine is fast.

the problem is the results are echoed before the timer/resultcounter thing is, because for it to count the results it already has to have the results and for it to display the time it took to find them obviously the search engine had to finish running.

i'm using html+css+php for this project and i don't want to have to use javascript, how should i display the timer / results counter before the actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `search` queries with the `time` code,  then echo them after the search has finished with the `time` code coming first.

```
$start = microtime(true);
$searchdata = //Search Functions    
$end = microtime(true);
$time = ($end - $start);
echo $time."".$searchdata
```

Comment: i didn't used your suggestion but it gave me an idea that was casting all the search results values to an array and then imploding it after outputting the time and number of results found. i was looking for a solution that would just ''regroup'' the things on the html/css page instead of this but i was tired of thinking and getting nowhere and decided to do this based on your answer. it slowed the search engine a bit more than i would like to but it still is fast as hell so i'll leave it that way. thanks

Comment: Cool, but I don't think it should slow down the search, since what your doing is just arranging the output. May be you shouldn't work with arrays.

Comment: maybe if i cast it to a string instead it's faster, i'll check it out when i can, but being a bit slower is comprehensible because the function was outputting the results directly to the page and now it has to store them in an array to output them at a later time. thank you for the comment

Comment: Yes. Casting would increase it significantly. Something like `$search .= "Search 1"`. . .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
$print=null;
$start=microtime(); 
echo 'etc etc you just found the results<br><br>'; 
$print= '<br><br>It took '. number_format(microtime()-$start,12).' seconds to find the results.<br><br>';
echo 'etc etc do what else is to be done, end of script<br>';
echo '__________________________________________________________<br><br>';
echo $print,'It took ', number_format(microtime()-$start,12),' seconds in total.'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $start_time = microtime(true);    
    .
    .
     //Search Logic
    .
    .
    $end_time = microtime(true);
    $time = ($end_time - $start_time);
    echo "Search Time : ".$time." sec\t";
```